# Bootstrap tooltip doesn't work (whatever I try)

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, tooltip

I'm trying to use Bootstraps tooltip. But I just don't get it working. Its not showing up. Whatever I try. I got all latest Jquery, Javascripts loaded. I tested if they actually work by the URL.

I followed many tutorials, read documentations, but no luck :/

This is my complete code with Javascript toggle: 
https://gist.github.com/matthijs110/1e7fc36902b0da5184aa

To save you the searching, here is the Script:

```
<script>
    $(function(){
        $('#domain').tooltip(animation)
        })
    });
</script>
```

And here is the text where it should toggle on hover:

```
<h4 id="domain" data-toggle="tooltip" title="first tooltip">play.domain.com</h4>
```

I just don't know what is wrong. I also tried the A tag. But I've read somewhere that H4 etc.. works too.

Answer (score 0):

You must use:

- jquery-1.8.3.js
- bootstrap.min.css
- bootstrap.min.js

I edited codes:

```
<div class='my_div'>
 <a href="#" class="marker" title="Tooltip on right">hover me</a>
</div>

<script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[ 
$(window).load(function(){
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".marker").tooltip({placement: 'right'});
});
});//]]>  

</script>
```

view on http://jsfiddle.net/ytpAy/314/

**Edited:**
For change the tooltip directions, on `placement: 'right'` use `bottom` , `top` , `left` or `right`

Comment: I don't know how much I can thank you! it finally works :D One more question tho, is it possible to center the tooltip?

Comment: @Matt: for show on center, on `placement: 'right'` use `bottom`

Comment: Ya I got that, but what I ment is, the tooltip itself, would be in the center of the text: http://puu.sh/8ZbRc.png

Comment: Ya I do. But the problem is, it messed up my navigation bar then: http://puu.sh/8ZhlJ.png padding is 0, it centers the tooltip to the middle then :) but with issues ^

Comment: First remove `bootstrap.min.css` from your code, then use css on this example: `http://jsfiddle.net/ytpAy/317/`

Comment: On my example you see I deleted `bootstrap.min.css` and code work good :| `http://jsfiddle.net/ytpAy/317/`